# How can i use form builder to save multiple instances of the same model in yii?

Tags: yii, formbuilder

My situation is like this.I have to save the present and permanent address of the same model Address in database.But it is saving the permanent address twice in database.How can I save the Present address?

```
$form = new CForm('application.views.user.addressForm');

 $form['prstAdd']->model = new Address;


$form['pmtAdd']->model = new Address;


 if($form->submitted('register') && $form->validate())

 {



  $prstAdd = $form['prstAdd']->model;



 if($prstAdd->save(false))




if($prstAdd->save(false))



  {




  $pmtAdd->save(false);




                       $this->redirect(array('site/index'));

   }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you  need to create  an array of model instances and then retrieve the user input data from the $_POST variable and assign it to each model.

Take a look at [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table)

Comment: I am using form builder.Can I implement this method in form builder?